# How to populate dropdown list with HashMap contained in an object, in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have an object containing a HashMap and some other variables. That's the class defining it:

```
public class Student {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String country; 

    public HashMap<String,String> countryOptions;

    public Student()
    {
        // populate country options: used ISO country code
        countryOptions = new HashMap<String, String>() {};

        countryOptions.put("BR", "Brazil");
        countryOptions.put("FR", "France");
        countryOptions.put("DE", "Germany");
        countryOptions.put("IN", "India"); 
    }

        // getters and setters...  
}
```

I wanna send that object to the form as a Model, bind data from that form with that object and then display it on a confirmation page. Unfortunately, I have a problem with populating the dropdown list with entries from the HashMap.

My controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/student")
public class StudentController {

    @RequestMapping("/showForm")
    public String showForm(Model theModel)
    {
        Student theStudent = new Student();     

        theModel.addAttribute("student", theStudent);
        theModel.addAttribute("country", theStudent.countryOptions);

        return "student-form";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/save")
    public String save(@ModelAttribute("student") Student theStudent)
    {
        return "student-confirmation";
    }
}
```

student-form.html:

```
<body>
    <form th:action="@{save}" th:object="${student}" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="firstName" th:field="${student.firstName}"/>
        <input type="text" name="lastName" th:field="${student.lastName}"/>

        <select name="country" th:field="${student.country}">
            <option th:each="country : ${student.countryOptions}" th:value="${student.countryOptions}" th:text="${student.countryOptions}"></option>
        </select>

        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>              
</body>
```

My result looks like this [image: my result]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Value and text attributes need to refer to `country`, otherwise thymeleaf will print `countryOptions.toString()`

```
<option th:each="country : ${student.countryOptions.entrySet()}"
        th:value="${country.key}"
        th:text="${country.value}">
</option>
```